# How to select appropriate checkbox in listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Please help, this (possibly simple) question makes me go crazy.

I have a custom listview containing textview and checkbox. 
I want to make an action on listview element when the checkbox is checked. I'm trying to use the code below, but the thing is I don't know how to detect which particular checkbox is clicked.

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.textCheckbox);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked)
        make some action
    else
        make another action
}
```

I have also tried to make checkbox react on OnItemLongClickListener:

```
OnItemLongClickListener LongListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.textCheckbox);
        listView = (ListView) a;
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
};
```

This way I can check a proper checkbox when I make a longclick on a listview item, but as soon as I scroll down the list, checkbox moves from it position.

Please advice!

Comment: http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: What layout are you using in your rows, do it implement Checkable?

Comment: I agree with you @Sam

Comment: @Sam I use my custom layout containing checkbox and textview.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to update the underlying data and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

```
OnItemLongClickListener LongListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        someListWithYourData.get(position).setSomething(true); // Now your data reflects the change
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for so prompt answer! 
if I write
    listView.get(position).setSomething(true); 
I get an error that "The method get(int) is undefined for the type ListView". what can i do?
and one more stupid question: what is meant by 'setSomething'? setChecked?

Comment: on which data do you build your ListView? Which data do are you giving to your adapter?

Comment: I have an arraylist with data